# React. Плагины для VS code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Посоветуйте плагин для VS Code, типа intellisense для поддержки React кода, чтоб давало подсказку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какие там могут быть подсказки? Функции и методы, а также значения vs code по-умолчанию поддерживает

Answer (score 1):

Синтаксис компонентов React внутри файлов js - фрагменты кода reactjs

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]